# MySQL TIMESTAMP to default NULL, not CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Using MySQL, I'm trying to make a timestamp column from a date column and a time column. If the date or time column contains a NULL value, MySQL automatically sets the corresponding value in the `TIMESTAMP` column to the [`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp).

Is there a way to make it default to a `NULL`, instead of the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

Something like:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD s_timestamp TIMESTAMP;
UPDATE customers
    SET s_timestamp = timestamp(s_date,s_time) DEFAULT NULL;
```

Answer (score 97, accepted):

Use this query to add your column

```
ALTER TABLE `customers` 
ADD COLUMN `s_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL;
```

And, if you want to get current timestamp on update only :

```
ALTER TABLE `customers` 
ADD COLUMN `s_timestamp` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: This worked for me. I created the table and while doing so I directly gave my timestamp column `NULL DEFAULT NULL` and it worked!

Comment: Earlier I was trying to create the timestamp column as `COLUMN_NAME DEFAULT NULL` which didn't work at all.

Answer (score 0):

To add to accepted answer in case someone is looking to modify an existing column that was created defaulting to current_timestamp:

```
alter table `customers` modify `s_timestamp` timestamp null
```

The column will now not default to current_timestamp anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst this seems to have been answered, we have a `createdAt` and `updatedAt` `TIMESTAMP(6)` columns.

```sql
  `createdAt` timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  `updatedAt` timestamp(6) NULL DEFAULT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
```

In our application code, we never set these values (unless fixing something and want to preserve the any original `updatedAt` or cloning/importing data and these values are known).

If you have null date/time when building your timestamp, then testing them first is the one viable option.

*UNTESTED*

```sql
UPDATE table SET column = CASE
  WHEN s_date IS NULL OR s_time IS NULL THEN null
  ELSE TIMESTAMP(s_date, s_time)
  END
```

From memory, the default behaviour takes place if the column is not mentioned in the query.

Answer (score -1):

I thought this should work:

```
ALTER TABLE customers ADD COLUMN s_timestamp TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL;
```

Comment: It doesn't.  `TIMESTAMP` columns have [special automatic behavior](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) when `NULL` is inserted, so if you really want to be able to set a null marker, you have to explicitly make the column nullable.

Comment: Duly noted, but the question is about MySQL behavior.